Are binding indices shared between shaders?
With glBindBufferBase and glUniformBlockBinding you can connect uniforms and buffers to supply the data to a shader.
Is the "binding point" (index) you bind buffers to shared between shaders? E.g. do you need to keep a list of what buffers are bound to what index so you can connect buffers you want to use for multiple uniforms in different shaders (e.g. a uniform that stores the viewport size) or can this be bound individually for each shader?

Buffer binding points are OpenGL context state, not state of the program. Which binding points the shader uses are part of the program's state. So you can "share" binding points by just having two shaders using the same binding points, but don't change what is actually bound between them.

So that means if two programs have a uniform that shares semantics I need to pass a reference of a common buffer to their initialisation code so they can both access the same data in that buffer AND I need to memorize on my own that "I bound this buffer to binding point 2, so all programs need to bind to that point too if they want to access this common datapoint".
EDIT: Well as long as I memorize what binding point the buffer used I do not even need to pass on the reference cause the programs do not need to know the buffer that is bound to their uniform binding points.

@salbeira: You don't really "memorize" binding points; that's just the point you use. Binding point X for these programs means "viewport and projection parameters". You can even have some global constants with these values in it.
